# How can I get the current URL from app request in Node JS/ Express?

Tags: node.js

I don't know if it is possible but im trying to save the URL that came from app.use in a global variable and trying to access it in the next line. It turns that in the second line the variable is undefined.

Here is my code in my Node JS file:

```
 app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   global.CurrentURL = req.protocol + "://" + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;
 });

   console.log(global.CurrentURL);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpGg2.png)

I need to save the current URL in the page so I can make validations with it. I think that the program doesn't go through that piece of code (app.use) is there any way I can force it to go through?

Comment: This snippet contains far too less information to be able to answer your question. But a few points to consider: 1. The callback of `app.use` is only executed, when there is a request to the server. It's not clear where that `console.log` is called, but when there hasn't been a request yet, `global.CurrentURL` will of course be `undefined`. 2) What happens if there are multiple parallel requests. You only have one global property, which will be overwritten by a later request ...

Comment: There seems to be some misconception from your side, how this async request handling works with express. You should probably read some tutorials on async programming in general and express in particular ...